# Euler/Fermat Modular Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you reduce $$3^{11^{13^{15}}}$$ modulo 11?  I have a similar question (not the same!) on an assignment and would like to see an example.

Comment: This one happens to be $1$ line, or less. Small change in numbers could give significant change in work needed.

Comment: a  better question would be 3^7^13^15 modulo 11...it is more related to the example

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

By Fermat's Little Theorem, we have that $\;3^{11}=3\pmod {11}\ldots$

Comment: Actually, $3^{5}\equiv 1\pmod {11}$.

Comment: @lhf Sure, one can resort to wit instead of knowledge! =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I didn't mean to be funny or anything. Just pointing out that the powers of 3 repeat earlier.

Comment: $$3^{11^{13^{15}}}=3^{11^k}=3^{11^{k-1}}\pmod {11}=\ldots$$

Comment: I don't think the order of $\;3\;$ modulo $\;11\;$ is what is needed at this question's level, @lhf...but I could be wrong.

Comment: @DonAntonio, the most elementary insight is to notice that the powers of 3 repeat. You try for a while and see that it repeats after 5 times. No need for Fermat-Euler. No mention of order modulo 11.

Comment: The question specifically mentions "modular primes", so why would we not use modularity?

Answer (score 1):

When you go up one tower, you have to work $\mod \varphi(11)=10$. But $11\equiv 1\mod 10$, so $$3^{\;\rm all\; that}\equiv 3^{?}$$